# Any way to pass in Masked Credit Card in Intent?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, cardreader

I am making a mobile POS and since the PayPal here credit card reader has no SDK for developers I am using a MagTek uDynamo credit card reader which has an SDK to get the users Masked Credit Card Number which looks like 4444********1111. I am using your Android SDK but I don't see any way to handle passing in a masked credit card number or even an unmasked credit card number. The project I am working on requires the user to scan their card using a card reader since it takes too long to sign into paypal or type the card number. I need someway to submit this masked card number to PayPal from my own Android Activity and charge the credit card. Is this possible now or will it be possible in the future? If not, then how do you suggest that I go about this? Also is there any plan of releaseing PayPay here SDK or supporting scanning with PayPal here in the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Looks like I was just looking at the whole picture the wrong way.